# Panel widget overlapping other contents in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to utilize the Panel widget introduced in [android-misc-widgets](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/). It's been good so far. Now the problem is the sliding panel overlaps my top menu bar. For clarification look at the following screenshots.

This is when I open panel using drag gesture (no problem here):
[image]

This is when I open the panel with a single tap (look at the icons overlapping the top menu):
[image]

There is one other problem, If there is any content inside the activity, opening the panel pushes that content out of the screen!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done with a `Relative Layout`. Positioning every item on the right place. here is the xml file if anyone ever faced the same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ms.rightel.store"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >
  >


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/categories" />

                <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/catsHList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp" >
                </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/latest" />

                <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/topHList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp" >
                </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
            android:id="@+id/panel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
            panel:animationDuration="500"
            panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"
            panel:content="@+id/panelContent"
            panel:handle="@+id/panelHandle"
            panel:linearFlying="false"
            panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
            panel:position="top" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panelContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/android_ldpi" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/android_ldpi" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/panelHandle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel>
 <include
            android:id="@+id/include1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/header" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```